# Hibernate not flushing out the results even after calling session.flush method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'am adding some record in db using hibernate, but when i try to get the same record in some millis then it is returning 0 results.

This is the flow:

1. Create a put request.
2. Put result in db.
3. Response received 202 accepted.
4. Then same controller sends the request to another controller which then tries to update that record.
5. It returns result as failure.

Environment:

1. JDK 8
2. Spring boot 1.2.5
3. Hibernate 4.3.11.Final

I tried following ways:

1. Set session flush mode to ALWAYS and COMMIT.
2. Manually did session.flush() and session.clear()

Please provide the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Try to debug it and look for the existence of the entry in the db right between 2. and 4.

Comment: What is your transaction state?  It doesn't matter if hibernate has flushed or not, if the TX hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: @SurinderRajpal Do you have the saving code being called in a transaction, say `@Transactional`?

Comment: Using transaction with following paramaters.
@Transactional(readOnly=false)

transaction is also commited.

Comment: Post some code. From your description there are at least 1234 different possible reasons causing the issue.

Comment: @Chris311 I Tried to debug but my ide is throwing some other exception like NoClassDefFoundException.

Comment: One more thing i want to ask is there any row lock mechanism in hibernate/mysql?? Because in one of my case, record is already there and we just try change its state only in both the cases(2 and 4).

Comment: @SurinderRajpal Try to add your project(s) to the classpath. I think debbuging would be really helpful here.

Comment: @Chris311 Everything was working fine some days ago. I haven't changed any classpath nor added any other project/library.